# Why does Combine's receive(on:) operator swallow errors?

Tags: swift, combine

The following pipeline:

```
enum MyError: Error {
  case oops
}
let cancel = Fail<Int, Error>(error: MyError.oops)
  .print("1>")
  .print("2>")
  .sink(receiveCompletion: { status in
    print("status>", status)
  }) { value in
    print("value>", value)
}
```

Outputs:

```
1>: receive subscription: (Empty)
2>: receive subscription: (Print)
2>: request unlimited
1>: request unlimited
1>: receive error: (oops)
2>: receive error: (oops)
status> failure(__lldb_expr_126.MyError.oops)
```

#### The problem

However, if I insert a `receive(on:)` operator into the previous pipeline:

```
enum MyError: Error {
  case oops
}
let cancel = Fail<Int, Error>(error: MyError.oops)
  .print("1>")
  .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
  .print("2>")
  .sink(receiveCompletion: { status in
    print("status>", status)
  }) { value in
    print("value>", value)
}
```

the output is:

```
1>: receive subscription: (Empty)
1>: receive error: (oops)
```

The `receive` operator seems to short-circuit the pipeline. I haven't seen it happen for other publishers, just when I use a `Fail` or `PassthroughSubject` publisher.

**Is this expected behavior? If so, what's the reason for it?**

---

#### Workaround

Here's an example of creating a failing publisher that works with the `receive(on:)` publisher:

```
struct FooModel: Codable {
  let title: String
}

func failPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<FooModel, Error> {
  return Just(Data(base64Encoded: "")!)
    .decode(type: FooModel.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

let cancel = failPublisher()
  .print("1>")
  .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
  .print("2>")
  .sink(receiveCompletion: { status in
    print("status>", status)
  }) { value in
    print("value>", value)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you're running into the same problem discussed in [this post](https://forums.swift.org/t/combine-receive-on-runloop-main-loses-sent-value-how-can-i-make-it-work/28631). Apparently  `receive(on:)` will send *all* messages asynchronously via the given scheduler, including subscription messages. So what's happening is the error is sent before the the subscription event has a chance to be sent asynchronously, and so there is no subscriber attached to the `receive` publisher when the next event comes in.

However, it looks like they are changing this as of [developer beta 1 of iOS 13.3](https://forums.swift.org/t/combine-receive-on-runloop-main-loses-sent-value-how-can-i-make-it-work/28631/39):

> As of developer beta 1 of iOS 13.3 (and associated releases for other platforms), we've changed the behavior of receive(on:) plus other Scheduler operators to synchronously send their subscription downstream. Previously, they would "async" it to the provided scheduler.

Comment: Aha! So the reason the workaround presumably works is because `.decode(type:decoder:)` is sending it's message asynchronously.

Comment: hmm, maybe. I don't know, the docs for `decode` don't say anything about running asynchronously. tbh I'm not clear why your workaround is working