# How to mock URLSession.DataTaskPublisher

Tags: ios, swift, mocking, urlsession, combine

How can I mock `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher`? I have a class `Proxy` that require to inject a `URLSessionProtocol`

```
protocol URLSessionProtocol {
    func loadData(from url: URL) -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher
}
```

```
class Proxy {

    private let urlSession: URLSessionProtocol

    init(urlSession: URLSessionProtocol) {
        self.urlSession = urlSession
    }

    func get(url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<Data, ProxyError> {
        // Using urlSession.loadData(from: url)
    }

}
```

This code was originally used with the traditional version of `URLSession` with the completion handler. It was perfect since I could easily mock `URLSession` for testing like Sundell's solution here: [Mocking in Swift](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/mocking-in-swift/).

Is it possible to do the same with the Combine Framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the same way that you can inject a `URLSessionProtocol` to mock a concrete session, you can also inject a mocked `Publisher`. For example:

```
let mockPublisher = Just(MockData()).eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

However, depending on what you do with this publisher you might have to address some weirdnesses with Combine async publishers, see this post for additional discussion:

[Why does Combine's receive(on:) operator swallow errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58945952/why-does-combines-receiveon-operator-swallow-errors)

Comment: I understand this concept, but how would you implement this? I'm struggling to return a URLSession.DataTaskPublisher in my mocked loadData function. Can you please give more details about this solution.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to test your client is to use `URLProtocol`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlprotocol

You can intercept all your request before she performs the real request on the cloud, and so creates your expectation. Once you have done your expectation, she will be destroyed, so you never make real requests.
Tests more reliable, faster, and you got the control!

You got a little example here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/153/how-to-test-ios-networking-code-the-easy-way

But it's more powerful than just this, you can do everything you want like: Check your Events/Analytics...

I hope it'll help you!

Answer (score 2):

Since `DataTaskPublisher` uses the `URLSession` it is created from, you can just mock that. I ended up creating a `URLSession` subclass, overriding `dataTask(...)` to return a `URLSessionDataTask` subclass, which I fed with the data/response/error I needed...

```
class URLSessionDataTaskMock: URLSessionDataTask {
  private let closure: () -> Void

  init(closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.closure = closure
  }

  override func resume() {
    closure()
  }
}

class URLSessionMock: URLSession {
  var data: Data?
  var response: URLResponse?
  var error: Error?

  override func dataTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
    let data = self.data
    let response = self.response
    let error = self.error
    return URLSessionDataTaskMock {
      completionHandler(data, response, error)
    }
  }
}
```

Then obviously you just want your networking layer using this `URLSession`, I went with a factory to do this:

```
protocol DataTaskPublisherFactory {
  func make(for request: URLRequest) -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher
}
```

Then in your network layer:

```
  func performRequest<ResponseType>(_ request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<ResponseType, APIError> where ResponseType : Decodable {
    Just(request)
      .flatMap { 
        self.dataTaskPublisherFactory.make(for: $0)
          .mapError { APIError.urlError($0)} } }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
```

Now you can just pass a mock factory in the test using the `URLSession` subclass (this one asserts `URLError`s are mapped to a custom error, but you could also assert some other condition given data/response):

```
  func test_performRequest_URLSessionDataTaskThrowsError_throwsAPIError() {
    let session = URLSessionMock()
    session.error = TestError.test
    let dataTaskPublisherFactory = mock(DataTaskPublisherFactory.self)
    given(dataTaskPublisherFactory.make(for: any())) ~> {
      session.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
    }
    let api = API(dataTaskPublisherFactory: dataTaskPublisherFactory)
    let publisher: AnyPublisher<TestCodable, APIError> = 
    api.performRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "www.someURL.com")!))
    let _ = publisher.sink(receiveCompletion: {
      switch $0 {
      case .failure(let error):
        XCTAssertEqual(error, APIError.urlError(URLError(_nsError: NSError(domain: "NSURLErrorDomain", code: -1, userInfo: nil))))
      case .finished:
        XCTFail()
      }
    }) { _ in }
  }
```

The one issue with this is that `URLSession` `init()` is deprecated from iOS 13, so you have to live with a warning in your test. If anyone can see a way around that I'd greatly appreciate it.

(Note: I'm using [Mockingbird](https://github.com/birdrides/mockingbird) for mocks).

Comment: iOS13 deprecated the normal DataTask `init()` which leads to a warning for your subclassed mock
`'init()' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Please use -[NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:] or other NSURLSession methods to create instances`