# How to mock DataTaskPublisher?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, combine

I'm trying to write some unit tests for my API using URLSession.DataTaskPublisher. I've found an already existing question on Stackoverflow for the same but I'm struggling to implement a working class using the proposed solution.

Here's the existing question: [How to mock URLSession.DataTaskPublisher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59521928/how-to-mock-urlsession-datataskpublisher)

```
protocol APIDataTaskPublisher {
    func dataTaskPublisher(for request: URLRequest) -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher
}

class APISessionDataTaskPublisher: APIDataTaskPublisher {
    func dataTaskPublisher(for request: URLRequest) -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher {
        return session.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
    }

    var session: URLSession

    init(session: URLSession = URLSession.shared) {
        self.session = session
    }
}

class URLSessionMock: APIDataTaskPublisher {
    func dataTaskPublisher(for request: URLRequest) -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher {
        // How can I return a mocked URLSession.DataTaskPublisher here?
    }
}
```

My API then uses the above like this:

```
class MyAPI {
    /// Shared URL session
    private let urlSession: APIDataTaskPublisher

    init(urlSession: APIDataTaskPublisher = APISessionDataTaskPublisher(session: URLSession.shared)) {
        self.urlSession = urlSession
    }
}
```

What I don't know is how to implement URLSessionMock.dataTaskPublisher().

Comment: You got some pretty awesome responses. Might wanna accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 26):

It would probably be simpler **not** to mock `DataTaskPublisher`. Do you really care if the publisher is a `DataTaskPublisher`? Probably not. What you probably care about is getting the same `Output` and `Failure` types as `DataTaskPublisher`. So change your API to only specify that:

```
protocol APIProvider {
    typealias APIResponse = URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output
    func apiResponse(for request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<APIResponse, URLError>
}
```

Conform `URLSession` to it for production use:

```
extension URLSession: APIProvider {
    func apiResponse(for request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<APIResponse, URLError> {
        return dataTaskPublisher(for: request).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

And then your mock can create the publisher in any way that's convenient. For example:

```
struct MockAPIProvider: APIProvider {
    func apiResponse(for request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<APIResponse, URLError> {
        let response = HTTPURLResponse(url: request.url!, statusCode: 200, httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1", headerFields: nil)!
        let data = "Hello, world!".data(using: .utf8)!
        return Just((data: data, response: response))
            .setFailureType(to: URLError.self)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `Just(_:).setFailureType(to:)`, you could use `Result.success((data: data, response: response)).publisher`, the failure type is inferred. It also works for testing error conditions: `Result.failure(URLError(.timedOut)).publisher`, or whatever URL error needed.

Comment: True. You can also say `Result.Publisher((data: data, response: response))` and `Result.Publisher(URLError(.timedOut))`, which are even shorter.

Comment: I had to use `let response: URLResponse = HTTPURLResponse(url: request.url!, statusCode: 200, httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1", headerFields: nil)!` to match the expected type.

Answer (score 2):

If you store in UT bundle stub JSON (XML, or something) for every API call that you want to test then the simplest mocking code might look as following

```
class URLSessionMock: APIDataTaskPublisher {
    func dataTaskPublisher(for request: URLRequest) -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher {

        // here might be created a map of API URLs to cached stub replies
        let stubReply = request.url?.lastPathComponent ?? "stub_error"
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: stubReply, withExtension: "json")!)
    }
}
```

so instead call to network server your publisher is created with URL of locally stored resource with known data, so you can verify all your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I will develop the step from having a simple Get request, to mocking .dataTaskPublisher for Combine and for the last part, testing the call. It is a ready to use code, for everyone in case someone else would need it.

Follow the comment to add your model or anything that depends on your project data.

So this is the protocol that give the rules to my NetworkRequest class:

```
protocol NetworkRequestProtocol {

  associatedtype Resource

  var resourceURL: NetworkEndpoint { get set }
  var resourceSession: URLSession { get set }

  func download() -> AnyPublisher<Resource, NetworkError>
}
```

There is some custom class, NetworkEndpoint and NetworkError, you can add your own here if you want or use URL and URLError instead:

```
enum NetworkEndpoint {

  static let baseURL = URL(string: "API_BASE_URL")! // Add your api base url here

  case live

  var url: URL {
    switch self {
    case .live:
      return NetworkEndpoint.baseURL!.appendingPathComponent("END_OR_YOUR_API_URL") // Add the end of your API url here
    }
  }
}

enum NetworkError: LocalizedError {

  case addressUnreachable(URL)
  case invalidResponse

  var errorDescription: String? {
    switch self {
    case .invalidResponse:
      return "The server response is invalid."
    case .addressUnreachable(let url):
      return "\(url.absoluteString) is unreachable."
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I am creating the NetworkRequest class to handle the API call. RessourceSession initializer is used for the UnitTest part only:

```
final class NetworkRequest<Resource> where Resource: Codable {

  var resourceURL: NetworkEndpoint
  var resourceSession: URLSession

  init(_ resourceURL: NetworkEndpoint,
       resourceSession: URLSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)) {
    self.resourceURL = resourceURL
    self.resourceSession = resourceSession
  }

  // MARK: - Dispatch Queues
  let downloadQueue = DispatchQueue(
    label: "downloadQueue", qos: .userInitiated,
    attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: .inherit, target: .main)
}

// MARK: - Network Requests
extension NetworkRequest: NetworkRequestProtocol {

  func download() -> AnyPublisher<Resource, NetworkError> {

    resourceSession
      .dataTaskPublisher(for: resourceURL.url)
      .receive(on: downloadQueue)
      .map(\.data)
      .decode(type: Resource.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
      .mapError { error -> NetworkError in
        switch error {
        case is URLError:
          return .addressUnreachable(self.resourceURL.url)
        default:
          return .invalidResponse }}
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

For the production code, this is an example of use of the NetworkRequest class, and of course, your model must be Codable:

```
var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

func downloadData() {
  NetworkRequest<YOUR_MODEL_NAME>(.live).download() // Add your model name inside the brackets
    .sink(
      receiveCompletion: { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .failure(let error):
          print(error)
        case .finished:
          break }},
      receiveValue: { data in
        print(data) })
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
}
```

So now that all the code is setup in the project, we can pass to the UnitTest part and start mocking URLSession:

```
class MockURLSession: URLSession {

  var data: Data?
  var response: URLResponse?
  var error: Error?

  init(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
    self.data = data
    self.response = response
    self.error = error
  }

  override func dataTask(with request: URLRequest,
                         completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
    let data = self.data
    let response = self.response
    let error = self.error
    return MockURLSessionDataTask {
      completionHandler(data, response, error)
    }
  }
}
```

Now, we mock URLSessionDataTask that we return when overriding dataTask in MockURLSession, and it will work for .dataTaskPublisher:

```
class MockURLSessionDataTask: URLSessionDataTask {
  private let closure: () -> Void

  init(closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.closure = closure
  }

  override func resume() {
    closure()
  }
}
```

We create fake response data to pass into our tests, but you must create a .json file with your data in it to fetch them in the  tests:

```
class FakeResponseData {

  static let response200OK = HTTPURLResponse(url: URL(string: "https://test.com")!,
                                             statusCode: 200,
                                             httpVersion: nil,
                                             headerFields: nil)!

  static let responseKO = HTTPURLResponse(url: URL(string: "https://test.com")!,
                                          statusCode: 500,
                                          httpVersion: nil,
                                          headerFields: nil)!

  class RessourceError: Error {}
  static let error = RessourceError()

  static var correctData: Data {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: FakeResponseData.self)
    let fakeJsonURL = bundle.url(forResource: "FAKE_JSON_FILE_NAME", withExtension: "json") // Add your fake json file name in here
    let fakeJsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: fakeJsonURL!)
    return fakeJsonData
  }

  static let incorrectData = "error".data(using: .utf8)!
}
```

And to finish, this is the part where you test your NetworkRequest, with the fake data coming from the .json file, or the error. You use resourceSession initializer to add your MockURLSession here and avoid making real network call:

```
class NetworkRequestTests: XCTestCase {

  var expectation: XCTestExpectation!
  var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable>!

  override func setUpWithError() throws {
    try super.setUpWithError()
    expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "wait for queue change")
    subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
  }

  override func tearDownWithError() throws {
    subscriptions = nil
    expectation = nil
    try super.tearDownWithError()
  }

  func testNetworkRequest_mockURLSessionAddCorrectDataResponse_returnRatesDataModelValues() throws {
    let expectedTestValue = "test" // This value is set in your .json fake data for testing

    // This is where you use resourceSession to pass your fake data
    let networkRequest = NetworkRequest<RatesData>(.live, resourceSession:
      MockURLSession(data: FakeResponseData.correctData,
                     response: FakeResponseData.response200OK,
                     error: nil))

    networkRequest.download()
      .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { completion in
          self.expectation.fulfill() },
        receiveValue: { value in
          XCTAssertEqual(expectedTimestamp, value.InFakeJson) // Compare with your fake json file
      })
      .store(in: &subscriptions)

    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 0.1)
  }

  func testNetworkRequest_mockURLSessionAddServerErrorAsResponse_returnNetworkErrorInvalidResponse() throws {
    let expectedNetworkError = NetworkError.invalidResponse.localizedDescription

    // This is where you use resourceSession to pass your fake data
    let networkRequest = NetworkRequest<RatesData>(.live, resourceSession:
      MockURLSession(data: nil,
                     response: FakeResponseData.responseKO,
                     error: nil))

    networkRequest.download()
      .sink(
        receiveCompletion: { completion in
          switch completion {
          case .failure(let error):
            XCTAssertEqual(expectedNetworkError, error.localizedDescription)
          case .finished:
            break
          }
          self.expectation.fulfill() },
        receiveValue: { value in
          XCTAssertNil(value)
      })
      .store(in: &subscriptions)

    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 0.1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Answered on original question, but will repost here:

Since `DataTaskPublisher` uses the `URLSession` it is created from, you can just mock that. I ended up creating a `URLSession` subclass, overriding `dataTask(...)` to return a `URLSessionDataTask` subclass, which I fed with the data/response/error I needed...

```
class URLSessionDataTaskMock: URLSessionDataTask {
  private let closure: () -> Void

  init(closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.closure = closure
  }

  override func resume() {
    closure()
  }
}

class URLSessionMock: URLSession {
  var data: Data?
  var response: URLResponse?
  var error: Error?

  override func dataTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask {
    let data = self.data
    let response = self.response
    let error = self.error
    return URLSessionDataTaskMock {
      completionHandler(data, response, error)
    }
  }
}
```

Then obviously you just want your networking layer using this `URLSession`, I went with a factory to do this:

```
protocol DataTaskPublisherFactory {
  func make(for request: URLRequest) -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher
}
```

Then in your network layer:

```
  func performRequest<ResponseType>(_ request: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<ResponseType, APIError> where ResponseType : Decodable {
    Just(request)
      .flatMap { 
        self.dataTaskPublisherFactory.make(for: $0)
          .mapError { APIError.urlError($0)} } }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
```

Now you can just pass a mock factory in the test using the `URLSession` subclass (this one asserts `URLError`s are mapped to a custom error, but you could also assert some other condition given data/response):

```
  func test_performRequest_URLSessionDataTaskThrowsError_throwsAPIError() {
    let session = URLSessionMock()
    session.error = TestError.test
    let dataTaskPublisherFactory = mock(DataTaskPublisherFactory.self)
    given(dataTaskPublisherFactory.make(for: any())) ~> {
      session.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0)
    }
    let api = API(dataTaskPublisherFactory: dataTaskPublisherFactory)
    let publisher: AnyPublisher<TestCodable, APIError> = 
    api.performRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "www.someURL.com")!))
    let _ = publisher.sink(receiveCompletion: {
      switch $0 {
      case .failure(let error):
        XCTAssertEqual(error, APIError.urlError(URLError(_nsError: NSError(domain: "NSURLErrorDomain", code: -1, userInfo: nil))))
      case .finished:
        XCTFail()
      }
    }) { _ in }
  }
```

The one issue with this is that `URLSession` `init()` is deprecated from iOS 13, so you have to live with a warning in your test. If anyone can see a way around that I'd greatly appreciate it.

(Note: I'm using [Mockingbird](https://github.com/birdrides/mockingbird) for mocks).

Comment: You can find a workaround for the deprecated init() in this Ray Wenderlich forum:

https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/chapter-8-init-deprecated-in-ios-13/102050/8