# How can I mock dataTaskPublisher method from URLSession in Swift Combine?

Tags: ios, swift, combine, urlsession, apiclient

I wan't to write a unit tests for my `APIClient`. This is the method I would like to test:

```
typealias ResponsePublisher<T> = AnyPublisher<T, APIRequestError>

func dispatch<T: Decodable>(request: URLRequest) -> ResponsePublisher<T> {
        urlSession
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
            .tryMap { data, response in
                if let response: HTTPURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                   !(200...299).contains(response.statusCode) {
                    throw APIClient.httpError(response.statusCode)
                }

                return data
            }
            .decode(type: T.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .mapError { APIClient.handleNonHTTPError($0) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
```

What is the best solution/approach on how to properly mock a `URLSession` with **mocked data, response** and **error** by overriding method from the `URLSession`:

```
func dataTaskPublisher(for request: URLRequest) -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher {}
```

which I use in `dispatch` method of the `APIClient`. In that case I would create an instance of a `mocked URLSession` and set it as `urlSession` property in my `APIClient`. It just needs to return mocked (data, response and error). Also the one possible limitation is with `URLSession.DataTaskPublisher`, since it is a `struct` it can not be overridden, so it can not be mocked directly. Thanks for your help and suggestions.

Comment: [First google result](https://medium.com/@dhawaldawar/how-to-mock-urlsession-using-urlprotocol-8b74f389a67a) for "mock urlsession datatask".

Comment: This is not the same thing. I do not want to use closures and mock with them, if I wanted to implement with those I would use damn closures. I want to mock publisher from the Combine framework. This is not a duplicate questions. I could not find anything on how to mock APIClient with the dataTaskPublisher.

Comment: But you would do the same thing with `dataTaskPublisher(for:)` as they do with `dataTask(with:)` in the other answer.

Comment: Or, instead try the approach used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61627636/9223839)